# Python for loop staying at 0

Tags: python, for-loop

I have written a small code that's supposed to read a list of prime numbers from a txt file and is supposed to generate the next ones.
For checking if my number is prime i try a division with every primes from the already generated list.
However, my for loop stays at 0 and I don't know why.
Here is my code:

```
primes = open("Primes1.txt").read().split()

primelist = []
for i in primes:
    primelist.append(i)
    print(primelist)

n = int(primelist[len(primelist) - 1]) + 1

print(n)

while n < 100 :
    n_prime = 1
    for i in range (len(primelist)) :
        print(i)
        if n % int(primelist[i]) == 0:
            n_prime = 0
            break
    if (n_prime == 1) :
        primelist.append(str(n))
        print(primelist)
        open("Primes1.txt", "a").write("\n" + str(n))
    n = n + 2
```

Comment: can you show us after print(n) what does it look like the output if you do `print(primelist)`?

Comment: can you show us content of `Primes1.txt` file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since the cause of your problem was in the text file, which you do not show in your question, this question is not helpful to others. So please delete this question. We look forward to more contributions from you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through every line of the text file first reading every line. Then you can append each prime to the new list. (This is if each number is on a new line) so for example:

If primes are on new lines:

```
primeFile = open("Primes1.txt", "r")
primeList = []

for prime in primeFile:
    primeList.append(prime)
```

If the primes are all on one line seperated by a space (" "):

```
 primeFile = open("Primes1.txt", "r")
    primeList = []

    for line in primeFile:
        primesInLine = line.split()
        for prime in primesInLine:
            primeList.append(prime)
```

This should do the trick either way

Answer (score 0):

Found the Problem. My Primes1.txt file had the folowwing numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7

on this line: n = int(primelist[len(primelist) - 1]) + 1,      n was set = 8

From this point, every single n was divisible by 2 (index 0) because of my n = n + 2